# If statement throwing error for nonexistent object

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

The answer to this question seems like it would be obvious, but I'm always looking to improve my semantics, so bear with me.

I have an array structure with individual items containing X,Y coordinates

```
var example = new Array();
example.push({x:0,y:0});
```

In my code I have a set interval that updates my canvas and checks for certain conditions. Including one similar to this

```
if(example[0].x == other.x && example[0].y == other.y)
{
//do something
}
```

The issue is that the array is very dynamic, and when the code is first executed the example array is empty. Hence, Chrome throws errors along the lines of "Cannot get property x". To shut up the console, I added a dummy item to the array {x:"~", y:"~"} but it seems really unintuitive. Have I implemented an undesirable data structure? What's a simple way to handle if statements for objects that... don't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just check whether the array has elements?

```
if (example.length && ...)
```

Or whether the first element is true:

```
if (example[0] && ...)
```

Comment: `example[0]` will fail for `[undefined]`, `[null]`, `[0]`, `[false]`... use only when you *know* beyond shadow of doubt falsy values can't be there.

Comment: It's supposed to fail for `[undefined]` and `[null]`. `undefined.x` and `null.x` will also throw exceptions (and `0.x`/`false.x` aren't sensible things to do either).

Comment: True; I didn't downvote or anything, just saying that it works in this situation, but it would be unwise to generalise and apply the same strategy in another situation. (I know it's bitten my lazy ass in at least one occasion when I assumed things I shouldn't have.)

Comment: @amadan—it's fine in this case as the members are supposed to be objects. But good to point out the limitations.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (0 in example
    && example[0].x == other.x && example[0].y == other.y) {
  // do something
}
```

(This works for arbitrary index, not just `0`; if you just want to check if the array is non-empty, `example.length` as shown by melpomene is good.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check on the first-level element (i.e. 'example') - JavaScript usually throws errors like this when you try to access a property of an element that is null or undefined. Like some others have already shown:

```
if(example[0] && example[0].x === other.x)
```

The point is though that JavaScript will let you have example[0] and return as you like, but once you try to access that property, you're out of luck:

```
var example = [];
//undefined
example
//[]
example[0]
//undefined <--- this is a falsy value, will evaluate false in a check
example[0].x
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```